# Open IDLE from Linux server

Tags: python, linux, python-idle

I am learning by using IDLE directly from my Mac.

I tried to do the same thing on a Linux server that I have access to, but I couldn't open IDLE there.

Here are things that I have tried:

```
$ idle 
==> -bash: /usr/local/Python-2.7.3/bin/idle: /usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory


$ /usr/local/Python-2.7.3/bin/idle
==> -bash: /usr/local/Python-2.7.3/bin/idle: /usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install python and IDLE? homebrew or something else?

Comment: Oops my bad. Are you trying to start IDLE program that exists on server? You may need an X server in addition to correct programs.

Comment: yeap!
that s what I asked XD im trying to start IDLE tht already exist.
What is X server? is it anywhere related to Xcode? XD sorry a real  newbie here

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting to the server via ssh -X username@ipaddress

The -X tells ssh to forward X11 data.

As others have said, though your errors look more like the idle/python combo on the server is not quite correct.  After you have fixed those problems you will likely need the -X option to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your script has a first line like this:

```
#!/usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7
```

But the file `/usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7` does not exist.

In most modern systems, if you change the first line of your script like this then it should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

When you write it this way, `bash` will use the `python2.7` interpreter, wherever it is. This is the modern way of writing Python scripts, because if you hardcode paths like `/usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7` then the script will only work in systems where Python is installed at that exact location, which is not flexible.

**UPDATE**

Actually, on a closer look, it seems that maybe you just need to rename the `/usr/local/Python-2.7.3` directory to `/usr/local/python-2.7.3` on the server. That is, all lowercase.

Comment: firstly, thank you for the answer :)


maybe I didnt make myself clear,
i could open python in the server, BUT i want to open a python shell like the one i used to use in my own computer, the window that open after i type "idle"

Comment: :( sadly, still giving me this  
-bash: /usr/local/python-2.7.3: No such file or directory

Comment: @PJA1 I think you misunderstood my answer. I meant to say, it seems you have a directory in the filesystem of the server called `/usr/local/Python-2.7.3`, and you need to rename this dir to be all lowercase. Try that.

Comment: i am not the admin, i dont think i have privilege to do so, am I? yeap...it says "Permission denied"

Comment: It seems the directory was incorrectly created. If you cannot change it then you could install Python inside your home directory.